# OO Javascript callbacks: Am I doing it right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Background: I am building a webapp that makes use of JQuery and the Facebook Javascript API. Since some users don't like Facebook, I have also built a thunking layer that emulates the necessary identity APIs for users who prefer not to use Facebook. To keep things clean and avoid code duplication, I have organized my Javascript code into a few classes.

Both Facebook and JQuery APIs make extensive use of callbacks. Since all of my functions are bound into objects, I found that I am using the following pattern frequently:

```
var obj_ref = this;
some_jquery_function_that_takes_a_callback(/* various args */,
    function() { obj_ref.my_callback_method(); });
```

For readability, the `obj` in `obj_ref` is actually the name of the class.

Is there some nifty Javascript magic that is simpler or clearer, or is this as good as it gets?

Update: Some good commentary so far in the answers. I should have added that my callback methods generally needs to refer to variables or functions bound to the class. If I don't need that, then the anonymous function wrapper is unnecessary.

Update2: I've selected a best answer, but you should carefully read all of the answers. Each provides some useful insight into possible solutions.

Comment: +1 for "am I doing this right?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need your `this` to be your `obj_ref` and you can assume an update to date JavaScript (which sadly you probably can't), you could use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to do away with the wrappers:

> Creates a new function that, when called, itself calls this function in the context of the provided this value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function was called.

Then you could bind your methods to your objects and this:

```
some_jquery_function_that_takes_a_callback(/* various args */,
    function() { obj_ref.my_callback_method(); });
```

would be the same as:

```
// In some initialization pass...
obj_ref.my_callback_method = obj_ref.my_callback_method.bind(obj_ref);

// And later...
some_jquery_function_that_takes_a_callback(/* various args */,
    obj_ref.my_callback_method);
```

Then `this` would be `obj_ref` when `my_callback_method` is called.

Alternatively, you could pull in Underscore.js and use its [`bind`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind) or [`bindAll`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll). You could always grab just `bind` or `bindAll` out of Underscore.js if you didn't want the whole thing.

Or, since you have jQuery in play already, you could use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) in place of the standard `bind`:

> Takes a function and returns a new one that will always have a particular context.

So you could do it like this:

```
// In some initialization pass...
obj_ref.my_callback_method = $.proxy(obj_ref.my_callback_method.bind, obj_ref);

// And later...
some_jquery_function_that_takes_a_callback(/* various args */,
    obj_ref.my_callback_method);
```

Thanks to [dsfq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq) for reminding me about jQuery's version of `bind`.

Comment: jQuery has built-in `proxy` function.

Comment: @dfsq: Thanks for the reminder, I've been using Backbone for the past year so I tend to reach for Underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use binding to the your object to preserve invocation context:

```
var objRef = this;

// #1. In this case you will have wrong context inside myCallbackMethod
// often it's not what you want. e.g. you won't be able to call another objRef methods
someJqueryFunction(a, b, objRef.myCallbackMethod);

// #2. Proper way - using proxy (bind) function
someJqueryFunction(a, b, $.proxy(objRef.myCallbackMethod, objRef));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with callbacks. Here's how I've dealt with it.

- Just like dfsq said, $.proxy does the job for you. You don't need any extra library like underscore.
- Underscore js has it's own bind function which is like the $.proxy.
- Apply and call (the javascript methods that can be called on functions) work great.

Let's say I have a object :

```
var Dog = {
   name : "Wolfy",
   bark : function(){
     console.debug(this.name," barks!");
   }
 }

 var AnotherDog = {
    name : "Fang"
 }

 Dog.bark.call(AnotherDog); //--> Fang barks!
 Dog.bark(); //--> Wolfy barks!
```

When you write your "classes", you could use this pattern to handle the invocation of callbacks.

In case you're not sure what proxy or bind do, they do something similar to this:

```
var Dog = {
   name : "Wolfy",
   bark : function(){
     console.debug(this.name," barks!");
   }
 }

 Dog.bark = funciton(){
     var scope = Dog;
     return Dog.bark.apply(scope,arguments);
 }
```

Rewrites the bark function by wrapping it in a new functions which returns the result of the original function, but forces a specific scope to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I usually only wrap the callback in a function when I have to pass in extra parameters:

```
var x = 42;
jQuery_something({}, function(y, z) { obj_ref.callback(x, y, z) });
```

And that is because you don't control the arguments passed into the callback yourself. But this is only if you need a reference to some var in the scope. And in some cases this means you will have to create a closure to capture the var, e.g. in a loop.

But if that's not the case, then I just pass in a reference to the function directly:

```
jQuery_something({}, obj_ref.callback);
```

Even `this` should work fine, since the callback reference is in scope in this particular example (so no need to copy it to `obj_ref` first:

```
jQuery_something({}, this.callback);
```

Obviously, the last example is about as simple and clean as it gets: "*the callback argument for the jQuery method is this object's method named 'callback'*"

Comment: That will work unless the callback method references any variables or functions bound to the class. I'll update my question.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your latter examples won't work if invoked within a callback themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is quite correct. You can have a helper function which implements the pattern though to save some code.